# Set image to ViewPager from List of Objects

Tags: android

I would like to make banner carousel. Instead of `RecyclerView` I choose to use `ViewPager`. I have a problems with adapter implementation:

```
public class BannerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    List<Banner> bannerList;
    Context context;
    ImageView imageView;

    public BannerAdapter(List<Banner> list, Context context) {
        bannerList = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment_home_layout, null);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        Picasso.with(context).load(OpApp.IMAGEORGINAL + bannerList.get(position).getMobileImage() + ".jpg").placeholder(R.drawable.op_logo).into(imageView);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bannerList.size();
    }



    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

The image is not loaded to the `ViewPager`.

`fragment_home_layout.xml`

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background">

    <-- Other Views -->

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/home_banner_carousel"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
                    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <-- Other Views -->


</FrameLayout>
```

Actual result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Additional to this question, what you can suggest to achieve position indicator functionality ? I think about `implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` but not sure with that.

I know how to implement 'ViewPager' using 'Fragments' but in my case I need to use 'List' instead of 'Fragments', and I'm confused with that.

P.S. Please don't minus my question, just comment what you don't like and what is wrong and I will try to edit it. I'm newbie here and in android. Anyway, Thank you!

Comment: You need a separate layout for  Imageview (like list_item_row for ListView) or Use ImageView = new Imageview(this).

Comment: I make `banner_row.xml` with `FrameLayout` as parent and one child. I move from `fragment_home_layout.xml` `ImageView` to the `banner_row` and change in the inflater from `fragment_home_layout` to `banner_row`, no result..

Answer (score 0):

Solution founded, I have changed adapter`s 2 methods and all is working!

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    Picasso.with(context).load(OpApp.IMAGEORGINAL + bannerList.get(position).getMobileImage() + ".jpg")
            .placeholder(R.drawable.op_logo).into(imageView);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView);
    return imageView;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
    ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
}
```